# Allow access from certain country only ( working example ) needs caching solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

In need for a chaching solution for a country based check. To only allow access to Rails application based on the country of visitor.

I have implemented below code:

```
allowed_countries:  ['US', 'FR']
```

And:

```
def check_country

  country         = GeoIP::Country.new(APP_CONFIG['geocountry'])
  country_result  = country.look_up(request.remote_ip) if Rails.env.production?
  country_result  = country.look_up("your_hardcoded_ip_here") if Rails.env.development?
  @country_code = country_result[:country_code]

  if APP_CONFIG["allowed_countries"].include?(@country_code)
    raise("accepted country")
  else
    raise("failed country")
  end

end
```

Works flawlessly ( you need geoip database which is payed search maxmind geoip )

BUT

This I have in a before filter, and need a good caching solution so it **does not gets called at each request**

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about storing a cookie on client side once validated ..?

Comment: @tihom rethinking this problem a cookie seems one of the few possibility's but, its not secure but it would prevent costly lookups in maxmind geo ip database so it could help a bit reduce the requests. I investigate this further thanks for the suggestion